# multiple binaries in a docker container based on scratch

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a spec for a container that requires two binaries to be executed one after the other. I would prefer to inherit from the scratch image so that the container is no larger than the sum of the two executables. The obvious way to accomplish this is to inherit from alpine or some other small OS but I'd prefer scratch. Also, the CMD, RUN and EXEC commands in the Dockerfile seems to require a shell and so scratch is not an option. Building two containers and then a docker swarm is interesting but not the answer.

Comment: Can your first executable start your second executable after it has finished? If not you'd need some other executable which executes the other two files one after the other.

Comment: Was about write exactly what @tkausl suggested. You can easily write a third binary in Go and run the other two executables. That is your only option, else you will need to go busybox or the alpine route

Comment: @tkausl, Tarun Lalwani - I suppose a "runner" would work. I would say there are two issues. [1] the smallest hello world app is going to be between 7 and 10MB. So a SIMPLE runner with limited error handling etc would have, roughly, the same size. [2] I have not determined why -e and --env-file are not working with "FROM scratch". Seems that some kind of shell is required in order for environment variables to be inherited or passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is here, so here are a few ideas.

First, you are correct that `RUN` requires a shell, but it doesn't sound like you need that.  You have two binaries, which we'll call `file1` and `file2`, and you just need to copy those into your image:

```
FROM scratch
COPY file1 /file1
COPY file2 /file2
```

If you only wanted to run a single executable, your life would be simple.  `CMD` does not require a shell, so you could simply add:

```
CMD ["/file1"]
```

Using the JSON version of `CMD` means that the binary will be executed without a shell.

While running a single command is easy, the fact that you want to run two different commands in sequence means that you need *something* to handle that workflow.  The easiest solution is a shell, because then you can simply run:

```
CMD /file1;/file2
```

But if you *don't* want a shell, then you would need to write a *third* binary that handles executing the first command, waiting for it to complete, then executing the second.  This would make your entire Dockerfile look like:

```
FROM scratch
COPY file1 /file1
COPY file2 /file2
COPY file3 /file3
CMD ["/file3"]
```

Unless you are planning on deploying in some unusually space-constrained environment, your time would probably be much better spent just using an `alpine` image or similar.

**Update**

Since it came up in the comments:

Using `-e` or `--env-file` does not impose any special requirements on the container.  For example, we can produce a container that contains only the `/usr/bin/env` command (and necessary shared libraries); the complete image source looks like:

```
Dockerfile
lib64/libc.so.6
lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
usr/bin/env
```

And a `Dockerfile` that looks like:

```
FROM scratch
COPY . /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env"]
```

And a file `bar.env` that contains:

```
BAR=somevalue
```

Assuming we build a container named "testenv", we can run:

```
docker run -e FOO=bar --env-file bar.env testenv
```

And see:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=f8f43505a272
BAR=somevalue
FOO=bar
HOME=/root
```

Comment: Your response is pretty close to the comments in the original question. I think you completely understood my question as the answer is the only solution I came up with. The challenge was getting an authoritative solution. This is emblematic of my biggest pet peeves with Docker which is that many and possibly most practical containers require a complete guest OS. (just try passing --env-file into a container without a shell; pretty certain it does not work [topic for another time])

Comment: I am pretty sure this answer directly addresses the points in your question.  If not, please let me know what I missed.  FWIW, I have not noticed any particular problems using `--env-file` without a shell.